# Windows File Explorer Not Displaying Desktop Correctly

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts, desktop

My file explorer isn't showing the relationship of the Desktop shortcut with other shortcuts correctly.

[image]

As you can see here, "This PC," "Libraries," etc., are showing under "Desktop," which is not what I wanted. I'd like all the shortcuts above to be displayed at the outmost level.

The only change that I've committed and relate is that I changed the directory of the desktop into this:

[image]

But I've done nothing other than I can relate to this problem. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can move and change the order of the shortcuts to where you want by clicking and dragging them.

Comment: @Ramhound the only other option that I have is to pin it to quick access, I can't throw it outside of either quick access or desktop

Comment: Try dragging and dropping `Network` onto `This PC` and see what happens.  You have restarted since you moved your Desktop to your OneDrive folder, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Navigation Pane` is in `Show all folders` mode. The **Desktop** at the top is the *virtual* Desktop, the root of the Shell [namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro), and all other items (even Quick Access), are children of it.

You can change the setting from the **View** ribbon:

[image]

Or right-click in the background of the `Navigation Pane`:

[image]